# Typescript create a type based of variable value

Tags: typescript

I have a array of shadow styles that looks like this

```
const shadows = [
  'none',
  '0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)',
  "...And more"
];
```

My goal is to be able to use them safely in my JSS with intellisense, so I have this to accomplish that

```
type Enumerate<
  N extends number,
  Acc extends number[] = []
> = Acc['length'] extends N
  ? Acc[number]
  : Enumerate<N, [...Acc, Acc['length']]>;

export type IntRange<F extends number, T extends number> = Exclude<
  Enumerate<T>,
  Enumerate<F>
>;

export const shadow = (num: Shadow) => shadows[num];
// This will make it possible to only input numbers from 0 to 24
export type Shadow = IntRange<0, 24>;
```

And using them like this in my components `boxShadow: theme.shadows(10)` and this will throw a error if out of range.

Instead of hardcoding 24 as maximum is it possible to utilize the length of the array here?
To have it be something like this `export type Shadow = IntRange<0, shadows.length>;`

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: You'd have to declare the array as `const shadows = [...] as const;`. Even if an array is assigned to a `const` variable, you can still push to it at runtime. The `as const` after the array literal is how you tell TypeScript that it cannot change in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your `shadows` a tuple (shortcut with `as const`), then you can use the length property, as it will be a number literal type:

```
const shadows = [
  'none',
  '0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)',
  "...And more",
] as const; // now type is a readonly tuple of length 3

export type Shadow = IntRange<0, typeof shadows["length"]>; // OK
```

[Playground (with 24 elements)](https://tsplay.dev/ND2pVW)